# Web application to store and query customizable data objects

Tags: web-apps, cms, content-filtering

A customer needs a website with the following requirements, is there something that does it out-of-the-box, or with minimal programming effort?

1. authenticated users should be able to create custom data objects, e.g. 'Cars' that have a list of properties like

   - 'Name' (string)
   - 'Category' (one of ['two doors', 'four doors', 'other'])
   - 'Sport' (boolean)
   - 'Luxury' (boolean)
   - etc.
2. unauthenticated users should be able to query the data using filters, like "return all cars that belongs to category 'four doors' with property 'Sport' and 'Luxury'".

Answer (score 2):

After some research i found out that there are products that allows this without any software development:

- WordPress, as a base web environment
- The [Pods Framework](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/) for inserting data objects in the WordPress backoffice
- [FacetWP](https://facetwp.com/) for building frontend forms that query the data base.

In this way there is no need to write a single line of code.

The only drawback is that FacetWP is a commercial plugin, but instead of spending hours of work for implementing the functionalities, I prefer to pay 99$ and have it for up to three websites.

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is one of [**Drupal**](https://www.drupal.org/)’s strengths.

#### Benefits

- Everything needed is free (GPL) and gratis.
- You don’t need to code (everything can be configured with the Web GUI).
- You don’t have to install any module (everything needed is built-in).

#### How to

1. Install [Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal).
2. Create a **content type** "Car" (under `/admin/structure/types`)

   1. Add the necessary fields to the "Car" content type ("Category" as select list, "Sport" and "Luxuary" as boolean, etc.).
3. Create a **view** "Cars" (under `/admin/structure/views`).

   1. Add the fields that should be displayed for each Car result.
   2. Add the filters. For each filter, check that it should be "exposed".
4. Done.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no out-of-the-box way to do that. What you asking for requires software development.

These two products are both database servers integrated with software  development environments aimed at producing  database-backed apps with relative ease.  Both are simple enough for beginners to get started but also powerful enough for professional software developers.

- [FileMaker](http://www.FileMaker.com/)
- [4D](http://htto://www.4D.com/)

The first is aimed at relatively simple database structures, mainly single tables. The second is a relational database for handling many interrelated tables.

Both provide their own clients. But as I recall both provide a web client capability, but I'm not sure how full-featured the web access is.

Otherwise you would use much more complicated web application development tools. Personally I use Java with the [Vaadin Framework](http://www.Vaadin.com/) to build the web app, and store data in the [Postgres](http://http//www.postgresql.org/) database. But there are many many other options.

Comment: Well, after some research i actually found our that there are products that actually allows having no software development: WordPress as base web environment, [the Pods Framework](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/)  for inserting data objects, and [FacetWP](https://facetwp.com/) for building frontend forms that query the data base. In this way there is no need to write a single line of code